# MFMailComposeViewController drawing bug?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In iOS 7.1 on the iPad, there seems to be a bug when selecting groups of contacts in an MFMailComposeViewController's "To" field. It appears that the table of groups draws on top of the table of contacts. Is there a known workaround?

[image]

Comment: that might be a problem in the simulator, but can you reproduce it on an actual iPad running iOS 7.1 ??

Comment: Yes, it happens on a real iPad.